# When I run sudo apt-get update I get "An error occured during the signature verification"

Tags: apt, root, vagrant

This is the error message I run into:

```
An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AA16FCBCA621E701.
```

Then I ran this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys AA16FCBCA621E701
sudo apt-key list
```

Just to make sure the key has been imported and it has. But I still keep getting the same error message when I run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Answer (score 0):

Under sudo:

```
wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg --fingerprint
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
apt update
```

Comment: Please expand a little on your answer...